# Is it possible to change the icon in the Android market?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in the Android market. I want to update that application with a new launcher icon. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it requires some work. Specifically, you'll need to change the app icon in your app in the project, rebuild the apk and upload/activate the new apk in the market's publishing area.  You also may want to update some of the graphics in the app description.

It's not possible to change the icon without re-building/re-uploading the apk, because the icon is stored inside the application apk file.

Comment: Thanks Aleks G for the quick reply